# How get paypal transaction detail in angular2?

Tags: angular, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox, angular2-forms

I am using paypal transaction for my site which is built in angular2. Here code of my paypal form. Component function.

```
paypalPayment(cartArr) {
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.method = "POST";
    form.action = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
    this.createElement(form, 'charset', 'utf-8');
    this.createElement(form, 'cmd', '_xclick');
    //this.createElement(form, 'cmd', '_cart');
    this.createElement(form, 'upload', '1');
    this.createElement(form, 'currency_code', 'USD');
    this.createElement(form, 'business', "my_business@mail.com");
    this.createElement(form, 'email',"user_email@test.com");
    this.createElement(form, 'custom', '{ "order_id": ' + this.order_id + ' }');
    this.createElement(form, 'item_name', "Item");
    this.createElement(form, 'amount', "10");
    this.createElement(form, 'quantity', 1);
    this.createElement(form, 'return', 'sitename.com/purchase/close_verified_order/' + this.order_id);
    this.createElement(form, 'cancel_return', 'sitename.com/purchase/cancel/' + this.order_id);
    this.createElement(form, 'notify_url', 'sitename.com/purchase/close_invalid_order/' + this.order_id);

    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
  }
```

In above form when i use `_xclick` then it returns basic detail like `transaction id` in `URL` but i need all transaction detail. Below is code of return page.

```
ngOnInit() {
    let transactionId = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['tx'];
    this.order_id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
  }
```

How paypal provide all transaction detail ? I have read about **IPN** but i don't know how to use it in `angular2`.

I want to know what should i have to change in my `notify_url` or in `return` to get all transaction detail. ?

If paypal send transaction detail in `POST` data then how can i handle that in `angular2` code ?

If i need to use IPN then how can i get `auth_token` from `paypal` and then how to call it's `api` from `angular2` ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't work with Angular, but in general, you need to set up a 'listener' to respond to IPN results. That 'listener' should include code that uses the $_POST data (returned to the 'listener') to do what you need with the info.

IPN docs start here https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/ . Set up a Sandbox account, and use that for testing.

There is also an IPN 'tester' that you can use to test your code against various types of IPN responses.